# jquery edit post with image missing something

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to make a post edit using jquery. But i have a problem with image think.

I have created this **[DEMO](http://codepen.io/shadowman86/pen/QNKwWo)** from codepen.io .

In this demo you can see there are two edit button. If you click the edit1 then the image delete `(x)` button will be come on the right top bar but that will come just one time. It need to be come two delete button because there are two image.  What is the problem on there and how can i fix that problems. Anyone can help me in this regard ?

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("body").on("click", ".editBtn", function(event) {
      event.target.disabled = true;
      var ID = $(this).attr("id");
      var selected = $("#messageB" + ID + " .postInfo img").parent().html();

      var currentMessage = $("#messageB" + ID + " .ptx").html();
      var editMarkUp = '<div class="edi"><div class="del">x</div>' + selected + '</div><div class="edBtnS"><div class="edSv">Save</div><div class="cNeD" id="' + ID + '">Cancel</div></div><textarea rows="5" cols="80" id="txtmessage_' + ID + '">' + currentMessage + '</textarea>';
      $("#messageB" + ID + " .postInfo").html(editMarkUp);
      var data = $('#txtmessage_' + ID).val();
      $('#txtmessage_' + ID).focus();
      $('#txtmessage_' + ID).val(data + ' ');
   });
   $("body").on("click", ".cNeD", function(event) {
      $(".editBtn").prop('disabled', false);
      var ID = $(this).attr("id");
      var currentMessageText = $("#txtmessage_" + ID).html();
      $("#messageB" + ID + " .ptx").html(currentMessageText);
   });
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="postAr" id="messageB1">
      <div class="postInfo">
         <img src="http://hdwallpaperia.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/Home-Sweet-Home-Wallpaper.jpg" id="1">
         <img src="http://www.dam7.com/Images/Puppy/images/myspace-puppy-images-0005.jpg" id="1">

      </div>
      <div class="ptx"> fdasfads fasd fadsf adsf adsf adsf asd fasd f dfsas</div>
      <div class="editBtn" name="edit" id="1">Edit1</div>
   </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
   <div class="postAr" id="messageB2">
      <div class="postInfo">
         <img src="http://cdn.theatlantic.com/assets/media/img/photo/2015/11/images-from-the-2016-sony-world-pho/s01_130921474920553591/main_900.jpg?1448476701">
         fdasfads fasd fadsf aldsf adsf adsf asd fasd f dfsassssg
      </div>
      <div class="editBtn" name="edit" id="2">Edit2</div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: quick demo here [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/RaGNgJ?editors=1010) a style is a bit broken but functions seems to work.

Answer (score 1):

I found that there are 2 main issues there.

1. you use html() function which get the HTML contents of the first element in the set of matched elements. take a look [document](http://api.jquery.com/html/)

> -> you will get html instead of src of img. But later when you try to set src attribute during creating an 'edit area' so that is the mainly reason why image doesn't
>   display (.attr() function is better to get src attribute)
>
> same wrong logic with message ( .text() function could be the better
>   solution in this case)

2. don't forget to check if you have create an edit area or not. At the moment every time it will create a new "edit area". Duplicate !

Hope it will help you a bit.